# Unable to get Salesforce ClientID and SecretID

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, credentials, salesforce-lightning, clientid

I'm attempting to use Outh authentication for my PHP request to Salesforce but I can't get my ClientID and SecretID for my app.
I normally have an option to View these values but for some reason I'm unable to view them with an administrator login.
I created a new App and was able to get the credentials successfully, so I know it's not the account permissions preventing me from accessing this information.
Does anyone with experience of Salesforce have any experience with an inability to get these details?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a normal app created in this org or managed connected app, coming from installed package? You can't see secrets of managed app.

For normal app they're hidden behind a button. For me clicking it takes me to email challenge (provide OTC or one-time code we've sent to your mailbox). Completing that I can access the page with key and secret I can copy-paste.

[image]

Your user might be misconfigured. Try to fish around with browser's source inspector, maybe the button's there but doesn't render?

```
<input id="appsetup:setupForm:details:oauthSettingsSection:manageConsumerKeySecretSection:manageConsumer" type="submit" name="appsetup:setupForm:details:oauthSettingsSection:manageConsumerKeySecretSection:manageConsumer" value="Manage Consumer Details" class="btn gsbutton">
```

Is your email valid in this org (maybe it's a fresh sandbox with ".invalid")? Do you use Multi Factor Authentication? Do you think you have "high assurance session" configured when accessing certain areas of setup? Can be in Setup -> Session Settings or in your Profile

Answer (score 1):

thank you for writing back to me regarding the issue.
The issue I encountered was trying to get the API credentials for an existing app but I was able to create a new App which is posting the Leads successfully into the system.
So the answer to my problem was that the original app was misconfigured when it was created and I was able to create a new App to resolve the problem.